# Angular service Call to method shows undefined error

Tags: angular

validation of username using API call
**In Signon.Component.ts**
this is the custom validation i used for username

```
  username : ['',[Validators.required,this.customvalidationService.userNameValidators]]});
```

**CustomValidationService**
**inject the service in CustomValidation service constructor**

```
    private userStatusservice:UserstatusService   
    { 
     
    }
```

*Call the API in the userstatusservice.ts**

```
userNameValidators(control: AbstractControl): {[key:string]:any} | null{  
    this.userStatusservice.ValidateUsername(control.value).subscribe(
        res => {         
          res.forEach(obj=>{
            if(obj.username==control.value)
            {
              this.user=obj;
            }
          })  
        });
    }
```

It showing an error Cannot read property 'userStatusservice' of undefined
I used bind(this)

> bind(this)

```
loginForm = this.fb.group({
  username : ['',[Validators.required,this.customvalidationService.userNameValidators.bind(this)]]});
```

it showing "Cannot read property 'ValidateUsername' of undefined"(this.userStatusservice.ValidateUsername(control.value))

Answer (score 1):

Since you're binding the `userNameValidators`'s `this`-reference to the component, it won't be able to resolve the `userStatusservice`-instance, which resolves in the error message you're receiving.

Maybe you should bind to `this.customvalidationService` instead, eg.:

```js
loginForm = this.fb.group({
  username : ['',[Validators.required,this.customvalidationService.userNameValidators.bind(this.customvalidationService)]]});
```

**EDIT:** Alternative to above!

Consider another alternative, having the `userNameValidators` become a factory for a validator, and "close over the service dependency", eg.:

```js
createUserNameValidators: () => {
    return (control: AbstractControl) {
        this.userStatusservice.ValidateUsername(control.value).subscribe(
            res => {
                res.forEach(obj => {
                    if (obj.username == control.value) {
                        this.user = obj;
                    }
                });
            });
    }
};
```

and then binding it to the formControl by:

```js
loginForm = this.fb.group({
  username : ['',[Validators.required,this.customvalidationService.createUserNameValidators()]]});
```

Comment: I've updated with an alternative solution, it would however be much easier to help with a "minimal reproduction" stackblitz example?